# Is it a best practice to use application.properties to hold business logic related properties in a spring application ?

Tags: spring-boot, properties-file

I have a spring boot application and i have a list of values that I use in my application. The list is static and the values are defines in application.properties for now .I get the values injected to my spring bean . I am a bit concerned about business logic specific values defined in application.prooerties . Though I can define in XML yaml etc , I wanted to have some expert opinion on using app.properties

Comment: As long as you are considering these values as configuration for your business logic, I think it is a reasonable practice.

Comment: You should however ask yourself whether in the long run you won't want these values being updated in real time via some API. When you reach that point you should probably move them to some datastore and read them dynamically

Comment: Addition to Shmulik's answer; You can use a config server to update your properties without restart your application. You can check [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/centralized-configuration/)